Hibernate not generating additional queries while fetching associated entities in eclipse console
Below is my Owning side Entity -
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;    
private IdCard idCard;

public Person() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_CARD_ID")  
public IdCard getIdCard() {
    return idCard;
}

public void setIdCard(IdCard idCard) {
    this.idCard = idCard;
}
}

Inverse side Entity -
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ID_CARD")
public class IdCard {
private Long id;
private String idNumber;
private Date issueDate;
//private Person person;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;

}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;

}
@Column(name = "ID_NUMBER")
public String getIdNumber() {
    return idNumber;

}
public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
    this.idNumber = idNumber;

}
@Column(name = "ISSUE_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getIssueDate() {
    return issueDate;
}
public void setIssueDate(Date issueDate) {
    this.issueDate = issueDate;
}
}

Persistence.xml -
<persistence-unit name = "RestSpringJPAPractice" transaction-type = "RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> 
    <class>com.practice.rest.spring.jpa.Person</class>
    <class>com.practice.rest.spring.jpa.Geek</class>
    <class>com.practice.rest.spring.jpa.IdCard</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      
      <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@somehost:someport:somesid" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="some_user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="some_pwd" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.cache.use.query_cache" value="false"/> -->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>    -->    
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
   </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>

Now for below code -
TypedQuery<Person> query = entitymanager.createQuery("from Person", Person.class);
        List<Person> resultList = query.getResultList();
        for (Person person : resultList) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(person.getFirstName()).append(" ").append(person.getLastName()).append("  ");
            IdCard idCard = person.getIdCard();
            if(idCard != null)
                sb.append(idCard.getIdNumber()).append("  ").append(person.getIdCard().getIssueDate());
}

Hibernate generates below query only -
select person0_.id as id1_2_, person0_.FIRST_NAME as first_na2_2_, person0_.ID_CARD_ID as id_card_4_2_, person0_.LAST_NAME as last_nam3_2_, person0_1_.FAV_LAN as fav_lan1_0_, decode(person0_.id, person0_1_.id, 1, 0) as clazz_ from T_PERSON person0_, T_GEEK person0_1_ where person0_.id=person0_1_.id(+)

My question -

How and when IdCard.idNumber and IdCard.issueDate is being fetched when the above query does not include IdCard table
why hibernate is not generating additional query for fetching IdCard when person.getIdCard(); is explicitly called
Is IdCard  is being fetched eagerly when the it is configured with FetchType.LAZY ? if so, where is the generated query?


Are you sure you have data in database? Can you check if your resultList has any person objects in it. You IdCard initialization is lazy so it will be called only if it will reach the code person.getIdCard();

Yes, there are multiple Person records present in T_PERSON table and records present in T_ID_CARD table as well. I was expecting that when person.getIdCard() is called, then it should fire a query like- Select * from T_ID_CARD where ID=<ID_CARD_ID-of-T_PERSON>;

you code is also reaching at the point IdCard idCard = person.getIdCard();?

Yes, absolutely. And it is also perfectly  printing the Person and IdCard details. For the sake of brevity I have not included the code to load Person, IdCard records into db.

person.getIdCard will not trigger a query. On the contrary idCard.getIdNumber() will. So make sure you get an idCard != null

But it is not generating the query during any of the below api calls -
person.getIdCard(), idCard.getIdNumber(), person.getIdCard().getIssueDate()

Hi anyone have any clue to my issue?

You have to do more to verify the data. For the person records you are looking at, do they have ID_CARD_ID values that match up to valid T_ID_CARD rows? How have you populated the database exactly and set the relationships in your Person entities? it also looks like you intended to have a bidirectional relationship but commented out the IdCard->Person field. Did you maybe have the relationship mapped incorrectly in the database when the data was populated?

Relationship, mapping everything is fine I guess, because I found the problem elsewhere. Before loading the records, I was not clearing the entitymanager. So, added entitymanager.clear(); before TypedQuery query = entitymanager.createQuery("from Person", Person.class); and it started working i.e I am now able to see the sql query when person.getIdCard(); is called in my code.

I have follow up question...is it always necessary to call entitymanager.clear(); before loading entities so that hibernate prints all the queries(including query for lazily loading associated entities) in eclipse console ?

no - if clearing the entityManager works, it means you are registering incomplete entity objects somehow with the relationship set to null/empty. So an issue with your application logic that causes the cached entities to not reflect the database data. How are you 'creating' these entities exactly? You should be able to see hte same results by forcing a refresh on the entity using em.refresh(person), but neither option is great as they are forcing database hits for data you obviously already loaded.
